# declaring too many global arrays (or IplImages) causing problems?

Tags: arrays, variables, opencv, global, iplimage

I have a general kind of question regarding globally declared arrays. I came across this issue. I cannot run my application several times at the same time anymore, I get a message (in German):

> die Auslagerungsdatei ist zu klein, um diesen Vorgang auszuführen (which translates to something like this: the storage file is too small to execute this process)

my question is: is this due to too many arrays declared as global or would the problem have to be related to something else, perhaps too many IplImages (I have declared hundreds of them as global) ? I have noticed that there seems to be a limit for the size of arrays in general. However, declaring several smaller arrays that sum up to much bigger size works - or at least up to a certain limit as well ... hence the problem above? What can I do to avoid this?

programming language: c++, vs 2008, console app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if your variables are global, local, class members, etc, for your question. The important fact is the lifespan of those variables. You can face memory problems if you load a lot of images at the same time. For example (let me use the C++ syntax with `cv::Mat` instead of `IplImage` -you should as well-):

```cpp
vector<cv::Mat> images;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
  images.push_back(cv::imread("image.png"));
```

This piece of code will allocate one million matrices with one million images. Of course, this is going to take a huge amount of memory and, probably, your program will crash.

Note that in C++, you can control the lifespan of your non-static variables by limiting their scope:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
{
  cv::Mat im = cv::imread("image.png");
} 
// im does not exist anylonger
```

In this code, you load an image one million times, but you only take memory for one image, because at the end of each iteration, `im` is deallocated. Note that in C, with the `IplImage`, you must deallocate the images by yourself with `cvReleaseImage`.

So, is it important that your variables are global? No, unless you don't control their lifespan and you keep them allocated all the time, even if you don't use them.

**Update:**
You can have local static variables whose lifespan is the entire time your app is running. These are not global (do not have a global scope) but they take memory all the time:

```cpp
void someFunction()
{
  static cv::Mat images[1000000];
  // one millon of matrices are allocated all the time, even when someFunction ends
}
```

Comment: I use global variables for several reasons, in particular that avoids certain things I'd have to take care of otherwise. I understand what you mean by lifespan of variables. I'm using local ones as well. Let me put it this way: if I have to turn certain globals into locals I have to take care of a lot of things what I'd rather like to avoid. But if it is necessary, i.e. if the mentioned error occurs otherwise, I'll do it of course. So that's why I'd like to know if the error is in fact due to too many globally declared arrays (or images) or not.

Comment: The error may be due to all the variables you have, but it is not because of their scope (global), but because they are alive all the time. Consider the example I have added: the variable `images` has a local scope, but the lifetime is the entire program, so all the memory is taken all the time.

Comment: okay, that's what I wanted to know. So I will need to make (at least some of) them local (& non-static, I guess that's what you wanted to say above, i.e. static variables are alive all the time, too). I guess the main reason why I chose to make them global was because I would have had to initialize all the elements of the arrays (I had noticed that the elements were non-zero if the arrays were local but uninitialized). Also there are many interwoven loops and functions in my app so that betimes it gets a bit difficult to know when they have to be alive and when not :D) Thank you!

Comment: It is usually a good design to declare your variables as close and local to the code where you need them. For example, you wouldn't declare the variable of a `for` loop as global, would you?

Comment: unless I use it in other for loops, true. Also if you have hundreds of for loops the mere act of typing (declaring) the variable each time instead of making it global may start to get a little annoying :D